# Access session info inside a separated module nodejs

Tags: node.js, session

I have the app.js with

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , MemoryStore = new express.session.MemoryStore
  , app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser('restservice'));
  app.use(express.session({store: MemoryStore, secret: '123456', key: 'sid', maxAge: 60000 }));
  app.use(routes);  
  app.use(app.router);
});
```

the routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express')
  , tools = require('./../functions')
  , app = module.exports = express();

app.get('/user/:id',tools.isAdmin,function(req,res){
    console.log('isadmin');
});
```

and the function.js

```
module.exports = {
  isAdmin: function (res,req,next) {
    if (req.session.level >= 16)
        next();
    else {
        res.json({result:-1});
    }
  }
};
```

So my problem is when I access http://myadmin.com/user/3 I get an error of `req.session undefined`

How can I from the point of functions.js view get access to the session information?

Comment: you have created two separate apps. i'm surprised anything is even logged.

Answer (score 0):

app.js and index.js are creating two different apps, two different instances of express - two different servers.

Since you aren't requiring one from the other (index doesn't require app, and app doesn't require index), when you run one, only that one is running. If you run `node app` only app.js runs, and if you run `node index` only index.js runs.

You should probably look at the basic express app examples included in express's github repository:

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples/mvc

Comment: From either app.js or index.js I can get req.session using the "node app" to initializate the server. My problem is inside the functions module. How can I get access to the req.session object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in this line

```
isAdmin: function (res,req,next) {
```

for some reason I switched the res with the req. With

```
isAdmin: function (req,res,next) {
```

now I can get the session info.

Comment: "for some reason I switched the res with the req." - The reason is you have to have a request before you can have a response. So it makes sense that the argument ordering follows this pattern.